# What version of python is compatible with GridDB?

Tags: python, database, time-series, griddb

Having some difficulties working with python 3.9 and griddb. Could you, please, tell me from your experience which works the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridDB (https://github.com/griddb/griddb) is Database for IoT with both NoSQL interface and SQL Interface. This is Python Client Library for GridDB.

Installation
Package dependencies

GridDB C Client
Download and install RPM or DEB package in GridDB C Client (https://github.com/griddb/c_client/releases).

Install RPM package by this command:

$ sudo yum localinstall package_name.rpm
Install DEB package by this command:

$ sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb
Pandas and Numpy
Install Pandas and Numpy by these commands:

$ python -m pip install numpy

$ python -m pip install pandas

Install the package by the following:

$ pip install griddb_python